# Backbone collection GET works, but PUT and POST both fail

Tags: backbone.js

Here is my code for my GET

```
singleChatModel = new Dashboard.Collections.MessagesCollection();
singleChatModel.fetch({
  data:{
        userId: userId,
        id: chatId
  }
});
```

and here is the C#

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?userId={userId}&id={id}")]
public MessageServiceModel[] GetAllMessages (string userId, string id)
{
....
}
```

the request URL

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1087/apps/messages/Messages/?userId=RJGILL&id=1
```

That all works great for the get, but I'm having trouble getting into the POST, PUT methods

Here is my POST

```
newMessage = new Dashboard.Models.MessagesModel;
newMessage.set(messageObj);
newMessage.save({
  success: function() {...}
});
```

and the C#

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?userId={userId}&id={id}", Method = "POST")]
public void AddNewMessage(string userId, string id, string text)
        {
            ...
            return;

        }
```

and here is the error that I get

```
POST http://localhost:1087/apps/messages/Messages/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

I need to manipulate the URL so that it is matches my UriTemplate.
Can I perform the POST / PUT with the same setup using the 'data' object as I am with the GET?

Comment: why do you want to post with 'data'? don't you just want to post the model instance?

Comment: Its a good point made by Mike Fielden. Your C# method signature should look like `public void AddNewMessage(Message msg)`. You could then decorate it with the `[HttpPost]` attribute and let model binding do the rest.